# Terraform aws_dynamodb_table_item resource fails when item contains List AttributeValue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, terraform

Trying to create a [dynamodb table item](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/dynamodb_table_item) resource which contains a DynamoDB List [AttributeValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html):

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table_item" "job" {
  table_name = var.some_table.id
  hash_key   = var.some_table.hash_key
  item       = <<ITEM
{
  "partitionKey": {"S": "JOBID#1"},
  "workloads": [{ "S" : "w1" }, { "S" : "w2" }]
}
ITEM
}
```

but fails with:

> Error: Invalid format of "item": Decoding failed: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type dynamodb.AttributeValue

Works ok if workloads is a string type e.g. `{"S": "w1"}` but not when a list. What am I doing wrong? Is this resource able to create List AttributeValues?

I'm using Terraform v1.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
  "partitionKey": {"S": "JOBID#1"},
  "workloads": {"L": [{ "S" : "w1" }, { "S" : "w2" }]}
```

where `L` is for list. The info about format is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html).